# Debug angular 2 application with webpack dev server

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular2-template

it is my understanding that webpack is the best way to use angular2. development for it has become a big hassle for me as I'm not sure how to debug it properly. on errors I get a big dump of errors with wrong line numbers and can't really debug the typescript application. I have been looking around for hours trying to find the right way to setup webpack and angular 2 to be able to debug efficiently but no luck

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Error in ./Trading class Trading - inline template:70:6 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefinedTypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined
    at Wrapper_SymbolSearch.subscribe (/TradingModule/SymbolSearch/wrapper.ngfactory.js:38:66)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Trading0.createInternal (/TradingModule/Trading/component.ngfactory.js:94:27)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:91690:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.create (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:92142:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_Trading_Host0.createInternal (/TradingModule/Trading/host.ngfactory.js:16:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:91703:21)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.createHostView (http://localhost:3000/vendor.bundle.js:92159:52)
...
```

is an example of the nasty stack trace dumped by `error_handler.js:51`. I've added angular loaders for webpack but I need a better way to package this in dev so it is easy to debug

```
  use: [
    '@angularclass/hmr-loader?pretty=' + !isProd + '&prod=' + isProd,
    'awesome-typescript-loader?{configFileName: "tsconfig.webpack.json"}',
    'angular2-template-loader',
    'angular-router-loader?loader=system&genDir=compiled/src/app&aot=' + AOT
  ],
```

Comment: `class Trading - inline template:70:6 caused by: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined` - Did you check that template and the function call?

Comment: yes of course line 70 is `</div>`. That's why I'm saying these errors are awful. Even sourcemaps aren't working properly

Comment: Search your template for `.subscribe()` calls.

Comment: Been working with angular 2 for a bit now, and those mystic errors seem to be par for the course.  Sourcemap is helpful in stepping through apps, not so much when they throw errors.  Anyways, if you use typescript properly (using types) it can catch a lot of these things before compiling.  But yeah, I feel your pain on occasion.  If there's a way to get better source maps on error, I'd love to know it.

Comment: There are absolutely 0 `.subscribe()` calls in my templates my friend. That is the first thing I look for. I commented out the entire template and error is still there so its not even the template, It's from a output binding `(myComponentOutput)="someVar"` for sure since if I remove that it goes away

Comment: Actually found the error to be that event emitter has to be initialized where it's declared and cannot be done in the `ngOnInit` method. Not the topic of this question but thought worth mentioning in case someone else has this problem